# PHP: How to push an array into a 2D array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-push

In Perl, we could do like this:

```
foreach (....) {
   ..........
   ..........
   ..........
   my @tmp = ($x1,$x2,$y1,$y2);
   push(@target_array,\@tmp);  # Don't know how to translate this line to PHP, failed after several try with array_push
}
```

How to translate this into PHP?

Comment: *Well..*, there is this function called `array_push()`.. seems pretty equal

Comment: what you have tried in php, please update with your question

Comment: or please show your desired array with before and after array values

Answer (score 2):

For add new array value you can use.
i assume that you have length for loop.

```
$target_array = array();
for(....) {
   ..........
   ..........
   ..........
   $tmp = array($x1,$x2,$y1,$y2);
   $target_array[][] = $tmp;
}
```

or you can

```
for(....) {
       ..........
       ..........
       ..........
       $tmp = array($x1,$x2,$y1,$y2);
       array_push($target_array,$tmp);
}
```

Comment: If I don't have a counter $i, how can I do this (like the example in Perl)?Or I have to add a counter in order to know what's the current last element in the target_array?

Comment: Yes you can push array in last by [ ][ ] in array.I update post